# Limit of a function approaching infinity with 2 constants.

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to +∞}{\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} - x}.$$
What is the limit of this function as it approaches infinity?

So in this limit, I tried inputting several values in the equation since it is approaching infinity, and I seem to get √bx + √c.

However, I don't think this is telling me anything. Am I reading the question from the wrong perspective?

Thanks

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and type out the questions and your work properly.

Comment: $\to +\infty$ or $\to -\infty$ which one ?

Comment: Sorry, it's positive infinity. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+bx+c}-x \right)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{bx+c}{\sqrt{x^2+bx+c}+x }\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{b+\frac{c}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}}+1 }\\
&=\frac{b}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hm, how did you go from the first step to the second step?
I presume the numerator is being divided by x? Unsure of the denominator.

Comment: both the numerator and the denominator are divided by $x$.

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't the denominator have a $c/x$ rather than $c/x^2$?

That is why I assumed I was incorrect

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks

Comment: The terms inside the square root are divided by  $x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to +∞}{\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} - x}=\\
\lim_{x \to +∞}({\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} - x})\frac{{\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} + x}}{{\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} 
+ x}}=\\
\lim_{x \to +∞}({x^2 + bx + c - x^2})\frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{x^2 + bx + c} 
+ x}}=\\
\lim_{x \to +∞}\frac{({ bx + c })}{{\sqrt{x^2 } 
+ x}}=\\=\frac{b}{2}$$